# Missing Manifest from docker

Tags: docker-registry, jfrog-container-registry

[image]
The remote Docker seems to be well configured but when I try to download any image to my virtual docker It always fails with this trace :

```
2020-04-01T16:20:32.969Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [b6e7232e6d2e0cb4] [DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:117] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'thanosio/thanos' and tag 'latest'
2020-04-01T16:20:33.874Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [b6e7232e6d2e0cb4] [.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:448] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Missing Manifest from docker-via-intranet 'v2/thanosio/thanos/manifests/latest' not found at docker-via-intranet:thanosio/thanos/latest/list.manifest.json
2020-04-01T16:20:34.703Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [b6e7232e6d2e0cb4] [.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:448] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Missing Manifest from docker-remote 'v2/thanosio/thanos/manifests/latest' not found at docker-remote:thanosio/thanos/latest/list.manifest.json
2020-04-01T16:20:35.545Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [b6e7232e6d2e0cb4] [.DockerV2RemoteRepoHandler:448] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Missing Manifest from quay-io 'v2/thanosio/thanos/manifests/latest' not found at quay-io:thanosio/thanos/latest/list.manifest.json
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DockerHub requires token authentication. You should check the "Enable Token Authentication" box. After doing this, try to pull an image you have never pulled before (since JFrog Container Registry caches 404s for a period of time). You can also go to the Advanced settings and set the missed metadata retrieval cache period to zero (instead of waiting for the cache period to expire).

Comment: It works fine for docker but not for Quay.io (https://quay.io/) Is there any specificity for this docker repository ?

Comment: quay.io also requires  "Enable Token Authentication". Also, note that you may have to uncheck "Block pulling of image manifest v2 schema 1" since quay tends to have a lot of images with the older manifest.